# Как получить позицию курсора мыши в ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses

Как узнать позицию курсора мыши, без её клика. Не положение, где будет писать сейчас клавитура, а именно мыши, которым я двигаю. `getsyx();` почему-то не работает.

Comment: Какая ошибка появляется при использовании `getsyx()`?

Comment: Ошибка не появляется, просто при попытке что то напечатать на этом месте, оно будто лесенкой вниз идёт.

Comment: А если попробовать использовать [`getyx()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37849/getyx-3curses.html)?

Comment: Когда использую `getyx()`, печатает тупо вряд